# Mongoose connects but Express 'get' returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to work on my local project on my new laptop. I pulled all my code from Github, set my environment variables the same as my old laptop, and configured MongoDB Atlas to allow access to my IP.

This is my connection code

```
mongoose.connect(
    DB_URI,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    async function (req, res) {
        try {
            await console.log("Connected to Database");
            console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
);
```

The `console.log` for the `readyState` returns 1 which means it connected according to the documentation.
The `DB_URI` is a private environment variable in another file, and I got it directly off of MongoDB Atlas.

This is the `GET` code I've tried

```
app.get("/path", function (req, res) {
    Model.find(async function (err, data) {
        try {
            await res.render("pathView", { data: data });
            console.log(data);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

and I also tried changing it to

```
app.get("/path", function (req, res) {
    Model.find(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(moves);
            res.render("pathView", { data: data });
        }
    });
});
```

but both of those only return empty arrays. The code works perfectly fine on my old laptop, but I've checked all the configurations and permissions and nothing is different.

The program connects to the database, the Model Schema hasn't been altered at all, the views load without any issue. It is just not getting the data from the collections.

Comment: The find method requires a filter, even if you want all documents.

Comment: I tried adding ```{ dataPiece: { $gte: 0}}, ``` before the function, but it still only returns an empty array